# Can autognomes be put to sleep by magic?

Tags: dnd-5e, racial-traits, sleep, spelljammer

So far, playable races that don't sleep explicitly also can't be put to sleep by magic:

***Warforged Constructed Resilience***: "You don't need to sleep, and magic can't put you to sleep."

***Elf Trance***: "Elves do not sleep." with ***Elf Fey Ancestry***: "...magic can't put you to sleep."

However, the recently released autognome breaks this trend.  It only says:

***Autognome Sentry's Rest***: "When you take a long rest, you spend at least 6 hours in an inactive, motionless state, instead of sleeping. In this state, you appear inert, but you remain conscious."

Does this mean that autognomes *can* be put to sleep by magic, even though they don't ever experience sleep naturally?

Comment: Related on [Does a homonculus need to sleep?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/82246/)

Answer (score 7):

The absence of trait or feature stating "magic can't put you to sleep" indicates that magic *can* put you to sleep. The races that cannot be magically lulled to sleep clearly indicate so in their race descriptions, as you have observed. As autognomes have no such trait in their race description, they can be put to sleep by magic. Looking outside the racial trait list, the race's brief lore description makes no mention of sleeping (or not sleeping) either.

Comment: *Boo's Astral Menagerie*, however, does give the [Autognome](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/2821155-autognome) creature a trait that indicates that they don't sleep. So, potentially only PC autognome's are affected by sleep spells?

Comment: @StarHawk Ah, but that just says they dont *require* sleep, not that they cant be put to sleep by magic.